# Can't receive Twitter authentication: "Error: object 'OAuthFactory' not found "

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

Problem occurs in RStudio, Version 1.0.153, on a Mac Sierra, version 10.12.6

I couldn't see any recent posts about this issue and suspect some packages might have been changed/ discontinued. This code used to give me Twitter authorization:

```
    install.packages("twitteR")
    library(twitteR)
    install.packages("RCurl")
    library(RCurl)
    install.packages("ROAuth")
    library(ROAuth) 
    install.packages("tm")
    library(tm)

#Run oauth code
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
twitCred <-OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                            consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                            requestURL=reqURL,
                            accessURL=accessURL,
                            authURL=authURL)
res <- twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey,consumerSecret,
                    access_token,
                    access_token_secret)
```

It now gives the following:

```
Error: object 'OAuthFactory' not found
```

However I'm directed to Twitter to copy the PIN. After pasting the PIN in the console I run the rest of the script

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey,consumerSecret,
                    access_token,
                    access_token_secret)
```

But this is followed by another error:

```
Error in setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, access_token,  : 
  could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"
```

I see many are using the [geoffjentry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=geoffjentry) authentication process. However, when I try to use this method I'm not given a PIN, so this isn't working for me either.

Thankful for help.

Comment: Maybe try following a more recent tutorial from scratch: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/collecting-and-mapping-twitter-data-using-r or https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/accessing-data-from-twitter-api-using-r-part1-b387a1c7d3e

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

These will have the same value:

**twitter_token and the access_token**

**client_twitter_id and consumer_key**

**client_twitter_secret and consumer_secret**

```
library(twitteR)

client_twitter_id <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
client_twitter_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

twitter_token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', twitter_token)


response = POST(
  'https://api.twitter.com/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(client_twitter_id, client_twitter_secret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
)

##token = content(response)$access_token
twitter_token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', twitter_token)




consumer_key <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
consumer_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Comment: Thank you, Nick. Your code worked. I think I was mostly confused with what I expected to see. The old code would open up a webpage to get a PIN, and authentication would be confirmed with "TRUE". Now it seems the confirmation is "Using direct authentication". I'm still having some issues with the error message: could not find function "searchTwitteR". I will have to look more deeply into that. But, despite the error msg I know I'm getting live tweets around the search words, because I get very recent ones containing the search word when I use the 'list' function.

Comment: Does this work? Try to not capitilize the R at the end: `searchTwitter("#beer", n=100)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried both, but both  searchTwitter() and searchTwitteR() render the "could not find" answer.